# Highcharts .update modifying original data array

Tags: javascript, arrays, charts, highcharts

I'm encountering a weird issue that's probably my doing but I've tried everything I can come across.

I have one stacked column chart with eight different data sets. I have a select field with the titles of each data set.

```
const charts = [
  {
    "title": "Chart One",
    "subtitle": "Subtitle One",
    "source": "<p>Source One</p>\n",
    "content": "<p>Content One</p>\n",
    "series": [
      {
        "name": "Legend One",
        "data": [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,null,0,0,0,0,null,0],
        "stack": 0
      },
      {
        "name": "Legend Two",
        "data": [1085,1364,2398,2362,3954,6612,6388,8841,8397,6021,null,4962,7407,2825,2143,null,4823],
        "stack": 0
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "title": "Chart Two",
    "subtitle": "Subtitle Two",
    "source": "<p>Source Two</p>\n",
    "content": "<p>Content Two</p>\n",
    "series": [
      {
        "name": "Legend One",
        "data": [380,608,469,285,634,1496,712,3059,1821,1049,null,916,2240,612,895,null,1064],
        "stack": 0
      },
      {
        "name": "Legend Two",
        "data": [705,756,1928,2078,3320,5116,5676,5782,6576,4973,null,4046,5167,2212,1248,null,3759],
        "stack": 0
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "title": "Chart Three",
    "subtitle": "Subtitle Three",
    "source": "<p>Source Three</p>\n",
    "content": "<p>Content Three</p>\n",
    "series": [
      {
        "name": "Legend One",
        "data": [648,932,1708,1326,2246,4646,4143,6732,6042,4222,null,3268,5723,1987,1501,null,3322],
        "stack": 0
      },
      {
        "name": "Legend Two",
        "data": [438,432,690,1037,1708,1966,2244,2110,2355,1799,null,1694,1685,838,642,null,1501],
        "stack": 0
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "title": "Chart Four",
    "subtitle": "Subtitle Four",
    "source": "<p>Source Four</p>\n",
    "content": "<p>Content Four</p>\n",
    "series": [
      {
        "name": "Legend One",
        "data": [380,608,469,285,634,1496,712,3118,2498,3567,null,1411,2687,698,1156,null,1479 ],
        "stack": 0
      },
      {
        "name": "Legend Two",
        "data": [705,756,1928,2078,3320,5116,5676,5724,5899,2455,null,3551,4720,2126,987,null,3344],
        "stack": 0
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "title": "Chart Five",
    "subtitle": "Subtitle Five",
    "source": "<p>Source Five</p>\n",
    "content": "<p>Content Five</p>\n",
    "series": [
      {
        "name": "Legend One",
        "data": [561,852,1362,2012,3404,5643,6195,8153,8158,5905,null,4502,6243,2646,1750,null,4305],
        "stack": 0
      },
      {
        "name": "Legend Two",
        "data": [524,512,1036,350,550,969,193,689,240,117,null,460,1165,178,393,null,518],
        "stack": 0
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "title": "Chart Six",
    "subtitle": "Subtitle Six",
    "source": "<p>Source Six</p>\n",
    "content": "<p>Content Six</p>\n",
    "series": [
      {
        "name": "Legend One",
        "data": [120,209,397,655,1115,2584,2944,3322,3075,2266,null,1751,2606,1032,740,null,1704],
        "stack": 0
      },
      {
        "name": "Legend Two",
        "data": [965,1155,2000,1708,2840,4027,3443,5519,5323,3755,null,3211,4802,1793,1403,null,3118],
        "stack": 0
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "title": "Chart Seven",
    "subtitle": "Subtitle Seven",
    "source": "<p>Source Seven</p>\n",
    "content": "<p>Content Seven</p>\n",
    "series": [
      {
        "name": "Legend One",
        "data": [294,494,391,800,1765,4227,5474,7212,7705,5836,null,3755,4640,2070,1463,null,3490],
        "stack": 0
      },
      {
        "name": "Legend Two",
        "data": [791,870,2007,1563,2189,2385,914,1630,692,186,null,1207,2768,755,680,null,1333],
        "stack": 0
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "title": "Chart Eight",
    "subtitle": "Subtitle Eight",
    "source": "<p>Source Eight</p>\n",
    "content": "<p>Content Eight</p>\n",
    "series": [
      {
        "name": "Legend One",
        "data": [486,741,1160,1825,3105,5205,6012,7553,7723,5780,null,4259,5754,2424,1596,null,4035],
        "stack": 0
      },
      {
        "name": "Legend Two",
        "data": [599,623,1237,537,849,1407,376,1288,674,242,null,703,1654,401,547,null,787],
        "stack": 0
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

When a user selects the chart they want to view, I then grab the data needed charts[selectedIndex].series and pass that to:

```
chartObj.update({
    series: charts[selectedIndex].series
}, false );
chartObj.redraw();
```

This overall works and the chart is updated correctly, however, `chart[0].series` gets updated with the last selected chart data. The chart array is getting modified for some odd reason. It only modifies the first chart in the array. For the life of me, I can't figure out why this is occurring. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

I've also tried a for loop going through the chartObj series and matching it to the desired charts array item, and using `.setData` with the 'data' but that had it's own issues. This did not modify the original array, however the chart would no longer update. I tried the same loop with .update as well.

Codepen with the error: https://codepen.io/rossberenson/pen/mdrWgPe

Comment: Because you have set `series:charts[0].series` when you initialize Highchart, when you update Highchart it is setting `charts[0]` to the new series. If you instead use a separate array for display, Highchart will update that instead and leave `charts` untouched. so `series: active[0].series` and make an array `const active =[...first object from charts array to start]`

Comment: @pilchard - Thank you for this. I think I understand. I updated https://codepen.io/rossberenson/pen/mdrWgPe.

I added const active, duplicating the charts array. Then when highcharts is initialized, it's looking at active[0].series. All good there, but when I go to update via selection. The charts array is being modified again. I assume it's because I'm not setting the series to be something else. I tried to then do a similar idea for the update.```const selectedChartData = [...charts[selectedChart].series];```but still have the same issue. Hmm

Comment: I see that you spread the charts array into the new active array. This was a good thought, but unfortunately cloning the array this way doesn't clone the nested objects, so when you switch the `series` it still updates the nested array in the original `charts` array. Instead, simply paste the entire first object in the `charts` array into the active array and then it works. (You could do this functionally, but  you'll need to clone every level of each object nested inside `charts`).

Comment: If you're curious, see: [What is the most efficient way to deep clone an object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript/5344074#5344074) if you'r curious.

Comment: @pilchard - Thanks for all of this. It's vert insightful, and I learned some new things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I dug a little deeper and found that the `chart.update()` call was switching out the nested `series` array but wasn't updating the entire chart object, more than that even cloning the `series` array using `map(o => ({...o}))` doesn't clone the nested `data` arrays so they are still prone to mutation. (you could use `map(o => ({...o, data: [...o.data]}))` but it's fragile if your series/data structure changes).

So... here is a quick snippet that stores the datasets in their own array and sets the `Highchart.series` option to a separate `active` object.

The `active` object is initially assigned a cloned version of the first chart object using `JSON` for deep cloning – see this question for deeper discussion of its shortcomings and better options [What is the most efficient way to deep clone an object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript/5344074#5344074)

When the select `change` event fires, the chart object at the newly selected index is cloned using the same method and assigned to the `active` object.

Finally, `chart.update()` is called pointing to the same `active.series` as when the highchart class was instantiated.

```js
const cloneSample = (sample) => {
  // Crude JSON deep clone – see referenced question for discussion
  return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(sample));
}

let active = cloneSample(samples[0]);

const highchart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: { type: 'bar' }, title: { text: active.title },
  xAxis: { categories: ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears', 'Grapes', 'Bananas'] },
  yAxis: { min: 0, title: { text: 'Total fruit consumption' } }, legend: { reversed: false },
  plotOptions: { series: { stacking: 'normal' } },
  series: active.series
});

const select = document.querySelector('.select');
select.addEventListener('change', () => {
  let
    selected = select.value,
    newSample = cloneSample(samples[selected]);
  
  active = newSample;

  highchart.update({
    title: { text: active.title },
    series: active.series,
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<select class="select">
    <option value="0">Sample One</option>
    <option value="1">Sample Two</option>
    <option value="2">Sample Three</option>
</select>

<div id="container"></div>

<script>
const samples = [
  {
    "title": "Sample One",
    "series": [
      {
        name: 'John',
        data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 2]
      }, {
        name: 'Jane',
        data: [2, 2, 3, 2, 1]
      }, {
        name: 'Tara',
        data: [3, 4, 4, 2, 5]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "title": "Sample Two",
    "series": [
      {
        name: 'Donna',
        data: [2, 1, 4, 6, 2]
      }, {
        name: 'Mark',
        data: [1, 4, 3, 4, 1]
      }, {
        name: 'Tim',
        data: [6, 4, 9, 3, 5]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "title": "Sample Three",
    "series": [
      {
        name: 'Mara',
        data: [3, 3, 1, 7, 2]
      }, {
        name: 'Tom',
        data: [0, 1, 2, 4, 1]
      }, {
        name: 'Lara',
        data: [3, 8, 5, 2, 5]
      }
    ]
  }
]
</script>
```

Comment: This helps a great deal. Thanks for all your help. I'm surprised that Highcharts works this way, and this is a work around that works. I know in the Highcharts docs it states that data might be mutated. I just didn't totally understand why it was. Thanks for clearing that up and providing an example of a solution.

Comment: I was surprised as well. I've made a small edit – `active` doesn't need to be an array, you can just assign the chart object to it directly.